# Changing color of ListBoxItem based on index

Tags: wpf, indexing, listbox, listboxitem

I am trying to change the foreground (text) color of one of the items in a ListBox based on an index value. For example, if the index was 1, then the item at index 1 would have a different text color than all the other items. The index isn't the list selection index but my own value.

I searched around on Google and found some ideas to use AlternationIndex but I can't get it to work that. The converter is either receiving 0 (zero) or DependencyProperty#Unset for the AlternationIndex binding.

Here is my code:

```
<ListBox x:Name="videoList" SelectionMode="Single" AlternationCount="{Binding Mode=OneWay, Path=Items.Count}" Grid.Column="1" SelectionChanged="videoList_SelectionChanged">
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Value="True">
                    <DataTrigger.Binding>
                        <MultiBinding Mode="OneWay" Converter="{StaticResource EqualityConverter}">
                            <MultiBinding.Bindings>
                                <Binding ElementName="videoWindow" Mode="OneWay" Path="VideoIndex" />
                                <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBoxItem}" Path="(ItemsControl.AlternationIndex)" />
                            </MultiBinding.Bindings>
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </DataTrigger.Binding>
                    <DataTrigger.Setters>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue" />
                    </DataTrigger.Setters>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```

For the RelativeSource I've tried: Self, TemplatedParent and AncestorType=ListBoxItem.
I also tried lots of different combinations with the Path value.

I can't get it to work. Any suggestions?

**Solution**: With the help from Clemens, turns out it was because the binding for the ListBox AlternationCount was incorrect. Oops!

```
<ListBox x:Name="videoList" 
         SelectionMode="Single" 
         AlternationCount="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Mode=OneWay, Path=Items.Count}" 
         Grid.Column="1" 
         SelectionChanged="videoList_SelectionChanged">
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Value="True">
                    <DataTrigger.Binding>
                        <MultiBinding Mode="OneWay" Converter="{StaticResource EqualityConverter}">
                            <MultiBinding.Bindings>
                                <Binding ElementName="videoWindow" Mode="OneWay" Path="VideoIndex" />
                                <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" Path="(ItemsControl.AlternationIndex)" />
                            </MultiBinding.Bindings>
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </DataTrigger.Binding>
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works with `RelativeSource Self` and a large enough `AlternationCount`, e.g. `int.MaxValue`.

```
<ListBox AlternationCount="2147483647" ...>
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Value="True">
                    <DataTrigger.Binding>
                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource EqualityConverter}">
                            <MultiBinding.Bindings>
                                <Binding ElementName="videoWindow"
                                         Path="VideoIndex"/>
                                <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}"
                                         Path="(ItemsControl.AlternationIndex)"/>
                            </MultiBinding.Bindings>
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </DataTrigger.Binding>
                    <DataTrigger.Setters>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue"/>
                    </DataTrigger.Setters>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```